# Setting up Erlang node fails with "Can't set long node name! Please check your configuration"

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-shell

```erlang
$ erl -name lofa
{error_logger,{{2008,6,18},{21,43,13}},"Can't set long node name! 
\nPlease check your configuration\n",[]}
# ... several stacktrace lines follow ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quoting José Valim](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-lang-talk/vcaT5T-0Ksw):

> This is likely happening because `hostname -f` is not returning a
>   value, i.e. your machine doesn't know how it should be named in the
>   network. You can use `--sname`, give the fullname, like `--name foo@IP_ADDRESS` or something that makes sense between machines (so they
>   can find each other).

Another solution is to [set the hostname directly](http://philips-tips.blogspot.com/2011/09/erlang-how-to-fix-cant-set-long-node.html) (`sudo hostname <FQDN>`), or update the hosts file (e.g., `/etc/hosts` in Linux).

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Use `erl -sname lofa` instead of `erl -name lofa`.

Explanation:

- `--name` expects a fully qualified name, i.e., `<username>@<host>`.
- `--sname` accepts a short name, i.e., just the username, inferring the host from `hostname -f`

Therefore,

```
iex --sname joe
erl -sname joe
```

is equivalent to the following

```
iex --name joe@$(hostname -f)
erl -name joe@$(hostname -f)
```

I tested the above from Elixir 1.7.4 & Erlang/OTP 22.3.4.20 up to 1.12.1 & Erlang/OTP 24.0.2 (the latest as of this answer).

**References**:

- [Naming Nodes - Programming
  Elixir](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-elixir/9781680500530/f_0146.html)
- [IEx — IEx v1.12.1 | Remote shells](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.12.1/IEx.html#module-remote-shells)